# Bash script calls a .js file with a function that should update global variable, but it doesn't

Tags: javascript, bash, global-variables

I have a `updateGlobalVar.js` file which looks as following:

```
var globalVar = 111;

async function setGlobalVar() {
    globalVar = 222;
}

setGlobalVar();
```

Also, I have a bash script, which retrieves that `globalVar` value, and looks as following:

```
#!/bin/bash

npm run /updateGlobalVar.js
GLOBAL_VAR=$(grep -Po '(?<=^var globalVar = ).*?(?=;)' ./updateGlobalVar.js)

echo $GLOBAL_VAR
```

The problem here is the bash script prints out initial `111` instead of an updated `222`.

The way I understand that flow is:

- `npm run /updateGlobalVar.js` runs `updateGlobalVar.js` (and I am sure it does);
- function `setGlobalVar()` is called (and I am sure it is);
- `globalVar` should be now updated and printed with a new `222` value. But it doesn't.

Moreover, when I modify my file to "debug" using the `console.log()` within the `updateGlobalVar.js` file like:

```
var globalVar = 111;
console.log(globalVar);

async function setGlobalVar() {
    globalVar = 222;
}

setGlobalVar();
console.log(globalVar);
```

It returns `111` in both `console.log(globalVar)` cases, which makes me think that `globalVar` is never updated.

Looks like I miss something fundamental regarding the work with global variables, still am struggling to figure that out.

May this be somehow related to the asynchronous nature of the `setGlobalVar()` function?

Comment: You grep for the definition of `globalVar` in the JavaScript source code. Do you think the source code of a program would magically change, when you run the program?

Comment: Well, I have explained the flow under my understanding, and I am confident it is wrong, that is why I made this question :) I expected that using a `grep` after code has finished will return me an updated value. But it didn't. So I am trying to figure out the proper why of doing it. If there is another way to assign an updated `globalVar` value to the bash variable, I'd be more than happy for help!

Comment: You never update the file. `grep` can't find something which is not there. Just do a `cat /updateGlobalVar.js` after you have run it: It did not change. If you want to assign the value of `globalVar` to a bash variable, you have two choices: Inside your Javascript program write it to stdout and process by bash this stdout. OR, write it to a file and process by bash this file.

Comment: Thx for those suggestions, will try it